# Git add patch (-p) with only one file?

Tags: git

I have a ton of modified files, but only a few that I actually want to cycle through with `git add -p`.

But when I run `git add -p file/path/name` it acts as if I didn't pass in the file path and presents the diff of the first modified file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

```
git add -p -- file/path/name
```

Using `--` to terminate options to the git command and introduce paths is common convention with the git tools and other Unix-style utilities.